# R and sparklyr: Why is a simple query so slow?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

This is my code. I run it in databricks.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)

sc <- spark_connect(method = "databricks")
tbl_change_db(sc, "prod")
trip_ids <- spark_read_table(sc, "signals",memory=F) %>% 
            slice_sample(10) %>% 
            pull(trip_identifier)
```

The code is extremly slow and takes in hour to run albeit I am only querying 10 samples.
Why is that? Is there a way to improve the performance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you're using `dplyr`'s `slice_sample` function to sample your dataset and then selecting some single column from there. The problem is that the Spark engine does not know about this: your sampling happens in R. This means that the full dataset is completely read from wherever it is stored, and completely sent to your R engine to only be subsampled in there.

What you need to do is to get your subset and column within Spark itself. You can do that with the [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/R/reference/select.html?q=select#null) (to grab a single column) and the [`head`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/api/R/reference/head.html?q=head#null) (to grab N rows) functions:

```r
trip_ids <- head(select(spark_read_table(sc, "signals",memory=F), trip_identifier), 10L)
```

Comment: spark is able to push down transofrmations its catalyst engine knows about. It doesn't know about anything defined outside of spark. They're a blackbox so it cannot make any optimizations. [Here's some reading on it](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs-blackbox.html).

Answer (score 2):

The other answer and comment already covered *why* the query was taking so long (you were pulling the entire table into the driver/R earlier than you wanted to), but I wanted to include an example that truly samples the data and another approach that gives you more control (i.e., one that uses SparkSQL). When working with Spark, I try to do all my heavy lifting as actual SQL queries so I would prefer option 2, but I included both in-case one is more helpful than the other.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc = spark_connect(method = "databricks")
tbl_change_db(sc, "prod")

# Option 1, using a fraction (proportion in this case) to pull a random sample
spark_read_table(sc, "signals", memory = FALSE) %>%
  select(trip_identifier) %>%
  sdf_sample(fraction = .0001, replacement = FALSE, seed = NULL) %>%
  collect() %>% #this is not necessary, but it makes the pull-down to R explicit
  pull(trip_identifier)


# Option 2, using SparkSQL to run the query as you intended (sampling 10 rows)
sc %>%
  sdf_sql("SELECT trip_identifier FROM signals TABLESAMPLE (10 ROWS)") %>%
  collect() %>% #this is not necessary, but it makes the pull-down to R explicit
  pull(trip_identifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should use Use spark_tbl() instead of
   spark_read_table(): The spark_tbl() function in sparklyr provides a
   more efficient way to create a Spark DataFrame by directly
   referencing the. table in Spark's catalog, without reading the entire
   table into R memory
2. And also you use sample_n() instead of slice_sample() for directly sample a fixed number of rows from Spark
   DataFrame

Like this example

```
trip_ids <- spark_tbl(sc, "prod.signals") %>%
  sample_n(10) %>% 
  pull(trip_identifier)
```

3. Also you can use arrow::arrow_serialize() and
   arrow::arrow_deserialize() functions to serialize and deserialize
   data between R and Spark.

I hope it should be usable